# Confusing C++ Template

Tags: c++, templates, struct, rvalue-reference, typename

I am studying C++ Templates. Can someone plaese explain every bit of this piece of code

```
template <class T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};
template <class T>
T&& forward(typename identity<T>::type&& a)
{
    return a;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of good perfect forwarding articles floating around.

Comment: @chris: Care to elaborate a bit? Perfect forwarding usually includes `remove_reference` in `forward` but here this is not the case, `identity` seems totally useless and the resulting forwarding is no more perfect.

Comment: @syam, I kind of saw that the function was named forward and jumped to conclusions. It would be interesting to know where this came from then.

Comment: @chris: My bad, the forwarding is still perfect (I think). But I still don't see the point of `identity`... I'll dig a little more and try to put up an answer if no one else has done so in the meantime.

Comment: I give up, after tinkering with it I am under the impression that this code is simply broken (but I could well be wrong, I'm no guru): it won't allow rvalue references. Let's hope someone else can shed some light on this. @Gaurav please tell us where this comes from, so we can at least know if the source is reliable.

Comment: @Gayrav where have you took this code from, what do you suppose it does ? Is it a tiny part from a bigger part you don't understand too ?

Comment: @syam I took this piece of code from this link [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html) in Perfect Forwarding Section. I am trying to understand templates, template template parameter but facing lot of difficulties in getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class T>
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

This part is defining a class template named `identity` that holds a public member `typedef` named `type` of the type you pass as the template argument. In your example there are no partial or explicit specializations so any type that is passed to `identity` is `type`.

```
template <class T>
T&& forward(typename identity<T>::type&& a)
{
    return a;
}
```

`forward` is a function template taking an rvalue-reference to the type returned by `identity<T>::type`. The type returned by `type` (however obvious it may be) cannot be deduced by the compiler to be `T` (because the type is a [dependent type](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html%E2%80%8E)), so you must explicitly specify the template argument for `forward`.

The rvalue-reference syntax `&&` (for the return-type) also denotes what is (informally) referred to as a *universal reference* since the type `T` is a template argument. This means the return-type can bind to both rvalues and lvalues returned by the function.

The parameter type `identity<T>::type&&` is **not** a universal reference because the type returned is not a template parameter. This means the parameter can only accept rvalues. That will require us to `move` lvalues into the parameter to `forward`:

```
int main()
{
    int n{0};
    forward<int>(std::move(n));
}
```

And in the end we return the parameter `a` to the rvalue reference. Note however that returning the parameter to `T&&` won't work because `a` will have to be *moved*:

```
template <class T>
T&& forward(typename identity<T>::type&& a)
{
    return std::move(a);
}
```

Otherwise return an lvalue-reference instead:

```
template <class T>
T& forward(typename identity<T>::type&& a)
{
    return a;
}
```

Comment: can u also explain in deep with an simple example where we can use template template parameter. I am trying to write a simple code of generic Stack where it can take any datatype, classes and i want to do it using template as an argument. I am able to write for generic type but not getting as to how to use template as an argument.

Comment: @Gaurav I think you should ask another question for that. But generally you would use the template-template parameter syntax when you are expecting a type (a class) that takes a template parameter, and you want to treat it as a template template class.

Comment: Ad `forward`: [temp.dep.type]/8 defines both `T` and any template with `T` as argument are dependent types. Following your logic, the compiler couldn't deduce `T` from `vector<T>& p` as a function parameter, as `vector<T>` is also a dependent type. I'd rather say it can't be deduced because of [temp.deduct.type]/5:1 (nested name).

Comment: @DyP maybe I used the wrong word. The `typedef` is dependent on the type `T`, which then makes the parameter in non deductible context. You have to apply the template argument.

Comment: @DyP Also, this isn't my code so I decided to leave in `identity` and make adjustments from there.

Comment: AFAIK that a type is dependent or not has nothing to do with whether it can be deduced or not. Of course we have a dependent type here `typename identity<T>::type`, but the reason why it cannot be deduced is AFAIK: "The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id." is a non-deduced context (where you have to explicitly specify the template argument)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need another specialization for `my_forward` to allow this call:

```
int a;
my_forward<int>(a);
```

So, specialize `my_forward` for references like this:

```
template <class T>
T&& my_forward(typename identity<T>::type& a)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(a);
}
```

But in this case, call for

```
int a;
my_forward<int&>(std::ref(a));
```

is ambiguous:

```
note: candidate function [with T = int &]
T&& my_forward(typename identity<T>::type&& a)
    ^
note: candidate function [with T = int &]
T&& my_forward(typename identity<T>::type& a)
    ^
```

To avoid it, you should use `std::remove_reference` instead of just `identity`:

```
template <class T>
T&& my_forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& a)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(a);
}

template <class T>
T&& my_forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& a)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(a);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `std::move` be effective in this case as well (instead of the cast)?

Comment: @0x499602D2, I don't think so, because `std::move` is just a cast too, isn't it?

Comment: It is, but I'm simply suggesting that you write that instead.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The Standard also specifies the return value of `forward` and `move` as a `static_cast`. To illustrate what the Standard does, I think `static_cast` is clearer.